# how c++ internally keeps track of what is allocated

Tags: c++, memory-management

I recently learned that in c++, when `new` keyword allocates a chunk of memory from the heap, the information about how it was allocated is stored right before it, and I wanted to see for myself.

So here's a little code I wrote:

```
void main() {
    char *cpptr;
    unsigned int **ptr;

    cpptr = new char[10];
    ptr = new unsigned int *;
    *ptr = new unsigned int[5];

    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 10; i >= -2; i--)
    {
        printf_s("%08x: %08x\n", (unsigned int)(cpptr - i), (unsigned int)(*(unsigned int *)(cpptr - i)));
    }
    cout << "------------------" << endl;

    cout << "==================" << endl;
    for (int i = 10; i >= -2; i--)
    {
        printf_s("%08x: %08x\n", (unsigned int)(ptr - i), (unsigned int)(*(ptr - i)));
    }
    cout << "==================" << endl;

    cout << "------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 10; i >= -2; i--)
    {
        printf_s("%08x: %08x\n", (unsigned int)(*ptr - i), (unsigned int)(*(*ptr - i)));
    }
    cout << "------------------" << endl;

    delete[] cpptr;
    delete[] * ptr;
    delete ptr;
}
```

And here's the result:

```
------------------
0061efc0: f2079dfe
0061efc4: 8a000fdd
0061efc8: 006194f0
0061efcc: 0061d040
0061efd0: 00000000
0061efd4: 00000000
0061efd8: 00000001
0061efdc: 0000000a
0061efe0: 0000008c
0061efe4: fdfdfdfd
0061efe8: cdcdcdcd
0061efec: cdcdcdcd
0061eff0: fdfdcdcd
------------------
==================
0061d038: 4539053b
0061d03c: 08000355
0061d040: 0061efc8
0061d044: 006139c8
0061d048: 00000000
0061d04c: 00000000
0061d050: 00000001
0061d054: 00000004
0061d058: 0000008d
0061d05c: fdfdfdfd
0061d060: 006139e8
0061d064: fdfdfdfd
0061d068: 4539053b
==================
------------------
006139c0: 4b390535
006139c4: 0800034c
006139c8: 0061d040
006139cc: 0061fc00
006139d0: 00000000
006139d4: 00000000
006139d8: 00000001
006139dc: 00000014
006139e0: 0000008e
006139e4: fdfdfdfd
006139e8: cdcdcdcd
006139ec: cdcdcdcd
006139f0: cdcdcdcd
------------------
```

The results have headers starting with two `00000000`'s before the address returned to the user program, and I can see that `0000000a`, `00000004` and `00000014` represent the size of the memory allocated in each allocation.

My question is, what do other lines mean? `0000008c`, `0000008d`, `0000008e` should mean the order each allocation was made, but why aren't they `00000000`, `00000001` and `00000002`? Also, I couldn't figure out what `00000001` part should mean. And do headers start with two `00000000`'s? I kept calling them 'headers', but is it even the right name?

Thanks.

Comment: This is entirely implantation defined behavior, it's up to your compiler.  If it's an open-source compiler (e.g. g++, clang) you could look at the code to see what this data means.

Comment: Sort of off topic: Don't count on anything you learn carrying over to other compilers, OSes, and CPU architectures. For one thing you might not even have a heap. Under windows I think the key term to punch into your favourite search engine is "Low Fragmentation Heap."

Comment: oh.. That makes sense. Since I use Visual C++, I guess it'd be difficult to find out. Thanks Paul.

Comment: Thanks user4581301. I'll look into it.